# On the supremum of cadlag function with bounded jumps

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum, upper-lower-bounds

For a function $f:[0,\infty)\rightarrow\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ that is a cadlag (right-continuous with left limits)  define
$$
T_n = \inf\{t\geq 0\mid \left|f(s)-f(0)\right|\geq n\}.
$$
Suppose that $|\Delta f(t)|=|f(t)-f(t-)|\leq C$ for all $t$.

I need to prove that

$$
\sup_{0\leq s\leq T_n}|f(s)-f(0)|\leq n+C.
$$

**My attempt**. Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ be given. The idea is that, for all $t<T_n$ we have $|f(t)-f(0)|<n$. We cannot conclude that $\sup_{0\leq s\leq T_n}|f(s)-f(0)|\leq n$ because it could be that $|f(T_n)-f(0)|$ is strictly larger than $n$. Whence

\begin{eqnarray}
\sup_{0\leq s\leq T_n}|f(s)-f(0)|&\leq& \max(n,|f(T_n)-f(0)|)\\ 
&\leq& n+|f(T_n)-f(0)|\\
&\leq&  n+|f(T_n)-f(T_n-)|+|f(T_n-)-f(0)|\leq n+C+n=2\,n+C
\end{eqnarray}

So my bound is not as tight as it should be. It is not super important, but since I have found in a book the bound $n+C$ I was wondering how to get it (or maybe my reasoning is somehow flawed).

**Bibliographic note.** The book I refer to is [Jacod and Shiryaev](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-662-05265-5)'s and the claimed inequality appears in the proof of Lemma I.4.24.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $0\leq s<T_n$; thus $|f(s)-f(0)| < n \leq n+C$ and the supremum inequality holds.

It remains to show that $|f(T_n)-f(0)| \leq n+C$. As the left limit jumps are bounded we know $$|f(T_n)-f(0)| \leq |f(T_n)-f(T_n-)|+|f(T_n-)-f(0)| \\\leq C+|f(T_n-)-f(0)|.$$ To complete this, we need that $|f(T_n-)-f(0)|\leq n$. This follows by taking the limit of $|f(s)-f(0)| < n$ as $s$ tends to $T_n$ from the left.

Comment: Two comments. 1) Since $|f(s)-f(0)|<n$ for $s<T_n$ taking the left limit (which exists) we immediately get $|f(T_n-)-f(0)|\leq n$, and we obtain what we need. 2) You say $\sup_{0\leq x<T_n}|f(x)-f(0)|<n$ but this is not true, as $\sup_{0\leq x<T_n}|f(x)-f(0)|=\sup_{0\leq x\leq T_n}|f(x)-f(0)|\leq \max(n,|f(T_n)-f(0)|)$.

Comment: Hi there. 1) Thank you, appealing to the continuity of the norm makes the inequality follow easily and the proof holds. 2) This is no longer needed due to the previous point but how do you know $\sup_{0\leq x\leq T_n}|f(x)-f(0)|\leq\sup_{0\leq x< T_n}|f(x)-f(0)|$?

Comment: Also I dont see how $\sup_{0\leq x<T_n}|f(x)-f(0)|\leq \max(n, |f(T_n)-f(0)|)$ disproves  $\sup_{0\leq x<T_n}|f(x)-f(0)|< n$, unless I'm missing something.